# String split gives array out of bounds

Tags: java, string, split

I am required to split a string which has been read from a external file. I have managed to split the string using this code;

```
String[] parts = line.split("\\.");
String part1 = parts[0];
String part2 = parts[1];
```

Now when I attempt to access the data, part1 at index[0] works fine, however trying to get index [1] throw an index out of bounds exception. The data I'm trying to split looks like so

> 886.0452586206898     27115740907.871643
>   888.0387931034484     26218442896.246094
>   890.032327586207     25301777157.154663
>   892.0258620689656     24365534070.686035
>   894.0193965517242     23409502709.11487

Am I meant to remove white space before doing the string split?

Comment: It should work...Are you sure that is the `String` you are splitting on?

Comment: It works for the index[0] and returns the 886,888,... just doesn't split the rest of the string up

Comment: Debug and have a look at what `parts` really is.

Comment: Show where you assign value to line.

Comment: Try to print or debug `line` and check if it really is what you think it is

Comment: Is that regex supposed to escape slash? if so, correctly breaks on second item.

Comment: Actually if you do a split on that string it gives 3 "parts". First: "886", second: "0452586206898 27115740907" and thrid: "871643"

Comment: @speirs23 why that? you need to escape the slash to be able to escape the dot, which in the other case would use it´s regex meaning.

Comment: The regex is supposed to escape period

Comment: Did you tried `String[] parts = line.split(".");` ?

Comment: @Gangaraju that wont work, since split does use regex.

Comment: Did you try `String[] parts = line.split(Pattern.quote("."));`?

Comment: `String line="886.0452586206898 27115740907.871643";
String[] parts = line.split("\\.");` will return 3 strings.

Comment: Debugging shows that the String[] has 3 indexes [0] = 886 [1] = 0452586206898 27115740907 [2] = 871643
indexing just seems to be lost when attempting to index the latter 2

Comment: @JordanFrampton i highly doubt that the indexing is lost. Could you include your actuall code. I rather guess that you are trying to acces something different in the later.

Comment: @Kevin
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
             System.out.println(line);
                String[] parts = line.split("\\.");
                String part1 = parts[0];
                String part2 = parts[1];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since i highly doubt that the index is getting lost. You might want to try this code to find out if the data is completly valid. If the error still occurs you might have the cause of the error at some different place, and want to show your actuall stacktrace.

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) { 
    if(line.contains(".")) {
        String[] parts = line.split("\\."); 
        String part1 = parts[0]; 
        String part2 = parts[1];
    } else {
        System.out.println("Corrupted data as: " + line);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not entirely sure why as every single entry contained a dot, but this code has worked. So thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are reading the file line by line, then you should split first against a "space" and then again the dot, otherwise you will get corrupted data...

> 886.0452586206898 27115740907.871643

as you can see, there are 2 elements in each line that can be split by dot

Comment: Yes, the data is read by BufferedReader, and then each line I wish to split by dot. Not sure what you mean by split against space and then again by dot?

Comment: It can be that at the end there is no dot split number..
if you find one line with an integer, then you will have that exception....

Comment: The file is made up of entries all of which look like that posted. Each line has at least one dot

Comment: is the followin entry in a file generating this output:
**886.0452586206898 27115740907.871643** -->
[0] = 886
[1] = 0452586206898 27115740907
[2] = 871643
????

Comment: Yes, when I debug, String[] shows has having three indexes which when I inspect those indexes it shows the correct three numbers. Then when I go to index String[1] for instance, I get index out of bound

Answer (score 0):

```
    String[] parts = null;
    String part1 = null;
    String part2 = null;


    System.out.println(parts[2]);
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
        parts = line.split("\\.");
        part1 = parts[0];
        part2 = parts[1];
    }
```

It is not working because you are trying to reach a variable that you declarated inside the while. Try to declarate outside it.

Comment: where did you get that information from? (it also makes no sense, since the code seems to be ok)

Comment: Sorry @KevinEsche, I posted that code underneath your comment earlier. However, this does not work anyway

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to extract each number from the input, then split on the decimal?
In that case, use Scanner to read in each number first, then split:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
while (s.hasNext()) {
  String num = s.next();
  String[] parts = num.split("\\.");
  ...
}
```